# Load local xml file to html in IE10 mobile browser fail

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, silverlight-4.0

I have loaded a xml for a cross platform application. it working fire in android an ios bit in **windows phone** it fails. I am having the html and xml in same folder.

```
 xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
 xmlDoc.async = false;
 xmlDoc.load('BranchDetail.xml');
 var xmlrows = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ROW");
 alert(xmlrows.length);
```

This method works in IE 10 Desktop browser. And I am using xmlhttp request method in android and Iphone. The xmlhttp request method is also **not working in WP8 IE10**

I tried using xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") also for WP IE 10.

Method used for android and ios:

```
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "BranchDetail.xml", false);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
  xmlhttp.send("");
  xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

Answer (score 0):

I edit my code using ajax like this now it works.For windows mobile IE10 we need to give a parameter isLocal to access the files in local folder.

```
 var url = 'BranchDetail.xml';
            $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                dataType: "xml",
                url: url,
                async: false,
                isLocal: true, // For the Windows Phone
                success: function (xml) {
                    $(xml).find('ROW').each(function () {
                        var title = $(this).find('BRANCH_EN_NAME').text();
                        alert(title);
                    });
                },
                error: function (xhr, error, exception) {
                    alert(" - Exception: " + exception);
                }
            });
```